# Two Virtualbox with two IP addresses

Tags: virtualbox, network-bridge

I am using Vitrualbox 6.0.8 on a server with ubuntu 18.04. Also i have 2 public IP: `a.a.a.a` and `b.b.b.b` that I have got from my hosting provider.

I need to run four VMS: 1-2 with public IP address `a.a.a.a` and 3-4 with IP address `b.b.b.b`.

Any help, please.

UPD1: bridge not helping because provider is checking MAC address.
NAT works fine (internet works) but 3-4 VM got ip `a.a.a.a` instead `b.b.b.b`.

Comment: You can use Bridge adapter to have that.

Answer (score 0):

So, maybe usefull for someone:
1. Create 2 host-only networks
2. Use rules:
For vboxnet0:
 `iptables -t filter -I FORWARD --in-interface vboxnet0 --out-interface INET --source 192.168.56.0/24 -j ACCEPT`
`iptables -t filter -I FORWARD --in-interface INET --out-interface vboxnet0 --destination 192.168.56.0/24 -j ACCEPT`
`iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o INET -j SNAT --to-source a.a.a.a`
Same for vboxnet1:
 `iptables -t filter -I FORWARD --in-interface vboxnet1 --out-interface INET --source 192.168.57.0/24 -j ACCEPT`
`iptables -t filter -I FORWARD --in-interface INET --out-interface vboxnet1 --destination 192.168.56.0/24 -j ACCEPT`
`iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o INET -j SNAT --to-source b.b.b.b`
3. Install dnsmasq